# How to generate custom form with FormBuilder in angular2

Tags: angular

I am working on angular2 application and I have requirement of building form with loop.

using : import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormArray, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

I have an array of industries = [1,2,3,4] (these are the ids of industries). I want to build different form for each industry. I searched alot but I didn't find anything.

Comment: create a 4 different component and include it in you main component and loop it check the conditions and display the form using *ngIf nad *ngFor

Comment: These industries ids are coming from api and they vary.

Comment: so every time check the value of ids the show the content like <div *ngIf="id==5">your component</div>

Comment: How to declare forms in typescript file?

Comment: forms are a .html file that is declared in the component.make a separate module for each component.and integrate that module in your main module where you want to show that.

Comment: Can you please give any reference.

Comment: [try this](https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-forms-reactive)

Comment: [try for nested](https://medium.com/spektrakel-blog/angular2-building-nested-reactive-forms-7978ecd145e4)